# How to write Iterm2 Scripts with single quotation marks

Tags: bash, terminal, iterm2

I'm trying to write a script in Iterm2

This should set a title on the current Tab

`await session.async_send_text('export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;TAB TITLE\007"'\n')`

But I'm getting error since the command entered has single quotations in it. How do I write the script correctly?

Sample script without single quotations:

```
await session.async_send_text('cd Documents/test1/test2/\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using double quotes for the outer quotes?

```
await session.async_send_text("export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne \"\033]0;TAB TITLE\007\"'\n")
```

Note the escaped inner double quotes.

Comment: I tried it and it's working when I'm entering this command directly in the terminal
`export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne \"\033]0;Admin Gateway\007\"'`

But since I'm using `\n` to enter or return, it doesn't work when running the script

Comment: Found out that when i'm running the script the \033 and \007 was automatically converted to special characters

This was the result:
`export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "^[]; Admin Gateway^G"'`

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a better way of doing this using PROMPT_COMMAND, but I found a package that can do the work, just install Tabset https://www.npmjs.com/package/iterm2-tab-set

```
npm i iterm2-tab-set
```

To set Tab Title: `tabset --title Test`